# reCAPTCHA box not showing up for some users

Tags: recaptcha

I am using reCAPTCHA v2 to protect the user registration form on my forums. I have recently been contacted by some visitors who simply don't seem to see the form at all.

It's very tricky to debug this since I can't reproduce the issue myself. But based on their comments it seems like they are getting `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when trying to download the reCAPTCHA Javascript file from `https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/`.

It doesn't seem to be browser specific and also doesn't seem to be isolated to a single country.

Has anybody else ever experienced this? My best guess would be that it's some sort of overzealous web filter blocking gstatic.com but I would have expected that to cause enough problems that it would have been fixed by now.

Comment: Many browser extensions can block Google trackers including reCAPTCHA. I personally use Privacy Badger from EFF. Have you had a chance to ask these users if they use privacy enhancing extensions?

Comment: As far as I know this is not the case but I'll double-check next time it happens. Does Privacy Badger block reCAPTCHA entirely? How do you deal with this on websites that require a CAPTCHA to sign up?

Comment: What is your website? Will try it on my privacy-hardened Firefox browser.

Comment: What happens when you look at the reCAPTCHA demo? https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Comment: Tried the demo before asking... Google hitting Google doesn't trigger Privacy Badger.